# c# combo box with time for timer to elapse

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-3.5

I have a program that disables the lockscreen and stop a service in windows. I have two buttons Enable,Disable and a combo box that has preset times. When My program is ran and the user clicks Enable the program should disable lock screen until the user manually
clicks disable. What I am trying to accomplish is to keep the program from running all night long if user never hits disable. So by selecting a preset time out of the combo box the program will auto disable it self.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DateTime time = DateTime.Today;
        for (DateTime _time = time.AddHours(16); _time < time.AddHours(18); _time = _time.AddMinutes(30))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(_time.ToShortTimeString());
        }
    }

    private static System.Timers.Timer _Timer;
    private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now;

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strTime_Start = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        string strTime_End = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;


        _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);
        _Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        DisableLock();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (strTime_End < DateTime.Now.Date) //I think this would be where I need to have strTime_End?
        {           
            _Timer.Stop();

            _lastRun = DateTime.Now;



        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm unsure about which *aspect* you need help with. You have several things to consider: a working regkey changer, a service, a UI update, and a state check, which part do you *specifically* want help with?

Comment: Adam Kewley If the time selected in the combo box is elapsed (16:00) for example then want it to go ahead and stop timer. Would it be something like 
`if (strTime_End < DateTime.Now.Date)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in my mind would be to keep an instance variable for your stop time, and each combobox item you have sets this stop time, the timer_tick event would simply check if it has passed that time. A blank item in the combo box can clear the variable.

```
private DateTime timeToStop;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        timeToStop = DateTime.Now.Add(DateTime.Parse(comboBox1.Text));
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        timeToStop = new DateTime(3000, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
    }
}

public void disableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Timer.Stop();
    _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now >= timeToStop)
    {
        _Timer.Stop();
        _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        // Disable regkey
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get `timeToStop = DateTime.Now.Add(DateTime.Parse(comboBox1.Text));` to work. I keep getting Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan'. Not sure what I have wrong.

Comment: `timeToStop = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(comboBox1.Text));`. You are going to run into a few problems working with Dates and Times in your future projects, my advice would be to read up the MSDN DateTime & TimeSpan .ToString() & .Parse() methods to see how they work. Decide on a near-universal format which is easy for you to understand in your projects (storage and calculations), and then worry about users local time cultures only as a display problem.

Comment: And enforcing a stringent input format (yours or theirs depending on your experience)

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood so far, you can just add :

> > comboBox1.Enabled = false;

when the time is elapsed, i.e. in the event.

Comment: I reworded what I was trying to do.
I have a program that disables the lockscreen and stop a service in windows. I have two buttons Enable,Disable and a combo box that has preset times. When My program is ran and the user clicks Enable the program should disable lock screen until the user manually
clicks disable. What I am trying to accomplish is to keep the program from running all night long if user never hits disable. So by selecting a preset time out of the combo box the program will auto disable it self.